# Divide part of a dataframe by another while keeping columns that are not being divided

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames as below:

```
   Sample_name   C14-Cer   C16-Cer    C18-Cer  C18:1-Cer   C20-Cer  
0          1 1  0.161456  0.033139   0.991840   2.111023  0.846197  
1         1 10  0.636140  1.024235  36.333741  16.074662  3.142135  
2         1 13  0.605840  0.034337   2.085061   2.125908  0.069698   
3         1 14  0.038481  0.152382   4.608259   4.960007  0.162162   
4          1 5  0.035628  0.087637   1.397457   0.768467  0.052605   
5          1 6  0.114375  0.020196   0.220193   7.662065  0.077727   


   Sample_name   C14-Cer   C16-Cer    C18-Cer  C18:1-Cer    C20-Cer  
0          1 1  0.305224  0.542488  66.428382  73.615079  10.342252   
1         1 10  0.814696  1.246165  73.802644  58.064363  11.179206   
2         1 13  0.556437  0.517383  50.555948  51.913547   9.412299   
3         1 14  0.314058  1.148754  56.165767  61.261950   9.142128   
4          1 5  0.499129  0.460813  40.182454  41.770906   8.263437   
5          1 6  0.300203  0.784065  47.359506  52.841821   9.833513
```

I want to divide the numerical values in the selected cells of the first by the second and I am  using the following code:

```
df1_int.loc[:,'C14-Cer':].div(df2.loc[:,'C14-Cer':])
```

However, this way I lose the information from the column "Sample_name".

```
    C14-Cer   C16-Cer   C18-Cer  C18:1-Cer   C20-Cer  
0   0.528977  0.061088  0.014931   0.028677  0.081819  
1   0.780831  0.821909  0.492309   0.276842  0.281070
2   1.088785  0.066367  0.041243   0.040951  0.007405
3   0.122529  0.132650  0.082047   0.080964  0.017738
4   0.071381  0.190178  0.034778   0.018397  0.006366
5   0.380993  0.025759  0.004649   0.145000  0.007904
```

How can I perform the division while keeping the column "Sample_name" in the resulting dataframe?

Comment: doesn't this work: `df1_int.loc[:,'C14-Cer':] = df1_int.loc[:,'C14-Cer':].div(df2.loc[:,'C14-Cer':])`? so you only overwrite the cols of interest but it leaves sample name untouched?

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. @EdChum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can selectively overwrite using `loc`, the same way that you're already performing the division:

```
df1_int.loc[:,'C14-Cer':] = df1_int.loc[:,'C14-Cer':].div(df2.loc[:,'C14-Cer':])
```

This preserves the sample_name col:

```
In [12]:
df.loc[:,'C14-Cer':] = df.loc[:,'C14-Cer':].div(df1.loc[:,'C14-Cer':])
df

Out[12]:
      Sample_name   C14-Cer   C16-Cer   C18-Cer  C18:1-Cer   C20-Cer
index                                                               
0             1 1  0.528975  0.061087  0.014931   0.028677  0.081819
1            1 10  0.780831  0.821910  0.492309   0.276842  0.281070
2            1 13  1.088785  0.066367  0.041243   0.040951  0.007405
3            1 14  0.122528  0.132650  0.082047   0.080964  0.017738
4             1 5  0.071380  0.190179  0.034778   0.018397  0.006366
5             1 6  0.380992  0.025758  0.004649   0.145000  0.007904
```